# 3D Carousel control available for UWP?

Tags: 3d, controls, carousel, uwp

i want to create carousel like this  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pARJ0.png) but i want it in UWP :/ Please can you help me..

Answer (score 4):

This http://blogs.u2u.net/diederik/post/2015/08/23/A-CoverFlow-control-for-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx what you are looking for?
It's not the exact same design, but you could tweak the code to give more space between the items of the carousel

Comment: i also need loop carousel but this example is not loop..  i want to image carousel not coverflow..

Comment: True, but the code is open source so it is a good start to further it to your needs I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:

https://github.com/XamlBrewer/Uwp.CoverFlowSample

More info here:

http://blogs.u2u.net/diederik/post/2015/08/23/A-CoverFlow-control-for-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx