# Get control inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

So I have a FlipView defined in xaml by the following code:

```
<FlipView x:Name="carrousel" Height="175" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
              <Rectangle x:Name="profile" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="175" Height="175" Canvas.ZIndex="1" RadiusX="88" RadiusY="88" Tapped="profile_Tapped"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

When a user clicks on the rectangle, it's animated to become bigger, but I also want all the other rectangles of every other FlipViewItem to change size too. How can I achieve this? I tried:

```
foreach(FlipViewItem fvi in carrousel.Items)
{
    Rectangle g = (fvi.Content as Grid).FindName("profile") as Rectangle;
    g.Width = double;
    g.Height = double;
}
```

But seeing as my flipview doesn't contain FlipViewItems but custom classes I've binded to it (which obviously have no .Content), it doesn't work. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Just i am curious. Looking into your control name, it seems to me that you are trying to achieve a carousel effect/control. Is this correct?

Comment: I was trying to modify my flipview to get a similar effect, but it kind of failed, so I abandoned and kept the name.

Comment: for carousel like effect you may follow [this]https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2015/05/26/windows-10-universal-windows-platform-carousel-control/ or [this]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008586/3d-carousel-control-available-for-uwp references.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still need to fix the problem in my post though...

Comment: I think carousel.Items is your datamodel class which you bound to FlipView. You should use ContainerFromItem(carousel.Items[i]) to get the FlipView item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(var fvi in carrousel.Items)
{
FlipViewItem item=carrousel.ContainerFromItem(fvi);
var rectangle =FindElementInVisualTree<Rectangle>(item);



//Or without VisualTreeHelper you can do like what were you trying before 
Rectangle g = (item.Content as Grid).FindName("profile") as Rectangle;
g.Width = double;
g.Height = double;
}

    private T FindElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
            {
                var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
                if (count == 0) return null;

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                        return (T)child;
                    else
                    {
                        var result = FindElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                        if (result != null)
                            return result;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a turn around solution (because I could not manage the relative binding).

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush}">
    <StackPanel Margin="100,10,10,10">
        <FlipView x:Name="carrousel" Height="350" Width="350" Background="Red" Margin="0,20,0,0">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="profile" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Aqua"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   Width="{Binding ElementName=RefValueRect, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                   Height="{Binding ElementName=RefValueRect, Path=Height, Mode=OneWay}" Canvas.ZIndex="1" RadiusX="88" 
                                   RadiusY="88" Tapped="profile_Tapped"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
    </StackPanel>
    <Rectangle x:Name="RefValueRect" Width="175" Height="175" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>
```

code behind

```
private void profile_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RefValueRect.Width *= 2;
    RefValueRect.Height *= 2;
}
```